# CodeIgniter on localhost not working

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, alias

So I downloaded a full website working on codeigniter and need to work on it, but it doesnt want to on localhost.

I created an Alias using the WampServer alias tool resulting in

```
Alias /spoco-origin/ "c:/wamp/www/spoco/origin/web" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/spoco/origin/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

the index.php file can be found in the web directory. Then my configuration :

```
$config['base_url']   = 'http://localhost/spoco-origin';
$config['index_page']    = 'index.php';
```

When I point to **localhost/spoco-origin**, I get a 404, and when I point to **localhost/spoco-origin/**, I get redirected to *www.localhost.com/* resulting in a 404.

Before this, I also tried to create alias using the **hosts** file, but it also gave me 404.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, hope you will not get any error

```
http://localhost/spoco-origin/index.php/[Controller-Name]/[Method-Name]/
```

Comment: make one controller method of name INDEX. and, in that method.. give it to INDEX address